# jQuery onClick row move row to another table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want when I clicked the row of table 1 then moved to row table 2, 
also in table 2 we could be canceled and then the row back to table 1.

any solution about this problem ?

```
var ids_selected = [];
var rows_selected = [];
$('#part-table').delegate('tr', 'click', function() {

if ($('#part-table #part-show tr').length === 1) {
    html = '<tr id="no-data"><th style="text-align:center;" class="table-conf even" colspan="13">No data found</th></tr>';
}
$('#part-table > tbody').html(html);

var $this = this;

var id = $(this).attr('id'),
         latest_no = $(this).children('td:eq(2)').text(),
         part_name = $(this).children('td:eq(3)').text(),
         loc;

rows_selected.push(this);
ids_selected.push(id);
loc = id.replace('id_part', '');
loctab = $.inArray(id, ids_selected);                                  '</tr>');
$('#partreq-table tr:eq('+loctab+') td:eq(0)').html(latest_no);
$('#partreq-table tr:eq('+loctab+') td:eq(1)').html(part_name+'<i class="fa fa-times eks" aria-hidden="true" id="'+id+'"></i>');
$(this).remove();});
```

[here is the pic of my tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25Drj.png)

Thank you

Comment: Please show your code and your attempt.

Comment: here it is my full script https://pastebin.com/f5Jnti6c

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a minimal working code sample (not a link)

Comment: okay edited , now could u help me ?

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: 1.12.4, here my problem is, the first data which i clicked doesn't moved, but with data 2 ,3 it's moved could u fixed my script ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the following example .

```js
$('tbody').on('click','tr',function(){
    myParent=$(this).closest('table').attr('id');
    if(myParent == "table1") $('#table2 tbody').append('<tr>'+$(this).html()+'</tr>');
    else $('#table1 tbody').append('<tr>'+$(this).html()+'</tr>');
    $(this).remove();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table1">
 <thead>
  <tr>
     <th>Month</th>
     <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>11</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>  
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>    
 </tbody>
</table>

<br/>

<table id="table2">
 <thead>
  <tr>
     <th>Month</th>
     <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>15</td>
  </tr>  
 </tbody>
</table>
```